# Как убрать шапку в приложении (Не ActionBar)

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, как называется эта полоска и как её убрать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это статус бар. Ищите про FullScreen

Answer (score 6):

Эта область экрана называется Status Bar.

Убрать Status Bar можно [несколькими способами](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html):

1. Задать тему `*.Fullscreen`:

   ```
   <application
       ...
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
       ...
   </application>
   ```
2. Программно:

   ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   } else {
       View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
       int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
       decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

В методе `onCreate`

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```